# How to remove 'active' class of nav-bar when clicked away?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am kinda new to this. I made a navbar that contains a button which toggles an 'active' class when clicked. I want to make it so when the navbar is opened and I click away it removes the 'active' class.
Although I used an eventListener (I don't know anything about those, so I Googled)

```
function toggle() {
    var navButton = document.querySelector('.nav-btn-container');
    navButton.classList.toggle('active')
}

var navBar = document.querySelector('#nav-bar');
navBar.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var isClickInside = navBar.contains(event.target);
    if (isClickInside && 
        document.querySelector('.nav-btn-container').classList.contains('active')){
        document.querySelector('.nav-btn-container').classList.remove('active');
    }
});
```

In VS Code I don't get any errors, but in the Chrome debugger I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

In the event function I used document.querySelector('.nav-btn- 
container') instead of navBar because if I move the navBar declaration outside of the toggle() class (on the first line) I get another error when I click the button:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: navButton is not defined
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>FCC: Product Landing Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="header">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" id="header-img">
        <button class="nav-btn-container" onclick="toggle()">
            <span class="nav-btn"></span>
        </button>
        <nav id="nav-bar">
             <ul class="nav-list">
                 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#features" class="nav- 
link">Features</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#video" class="nav- 
link">Unboxing</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#purchase" class="nav- 
link">Purchase</a></li>
                 <li class="nav-item"><a href="#reviews" class="nav- 
link">Reviews</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main> 
        <section class="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Hover over the world</h1>
                <h2>Reach fast speeds</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="features">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Hover over the world</h1>
                <h2>Reach fast speeds</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="video">
            <div class="container"></div>
</section>

        <section class="purchase">
            <div class="container"></div>
        </section>

        <section class="reviews">
            <div class="container"></div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS: https://pastebin.com/Zd7DFCca

Comment: Are you sure that you have an element in your dom with id="nav-bar" ? + Where you are putting you're script, you're sure that it can access the DOM ?

Comment: that error it's because the DOM element is not getting selected properly. probably the problem is not in your JavaScript but rather in your HTML. can you add your HTML code too

Comment: Yes, I checked it before posting the question there's a <nav id="nav-bar">

Comment: Post your HTML here.

Comment: Done. I edited the post

Comment: first, it's best practice to add your JS in the body before the close tag

Comment: Solution: I believe in Your case the problem is about the order of loading this js file.

Please put the script at the end of the file before closing the body tag.

Comment: I don't get any errors anymore, but it still doesn't work, the class isn't removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `head` tag insert this jquery reference script

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
.
.
.
</head>
```

what needs to be done is to add a mouse click `event` , on click the code should check if the click was outside the `nav` container, if true, `active` will be removed from it:

in your `js` script file
replace the `js` code that you posted by this:

```js
function toggle() {
    var navButton = document.querySelector('.nav-btn-container');
    navButton.classList.toggle('active')
}

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("header");
    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        document.querySelector('.nav-btn-container').classList.remove('active');

    }
});
```

Moreover instead of placing your `<script src="script.js"></script>` in the `head`, you should place in the bottom of the `body`

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean I don't understand the "now after logging the navbar"

Comment: I am displaying the result as a proof. the query selector is now returning the navbar instead of returning null which was the cause of the null reference error that you were gotten.

Comment: Okay, I don't get any errors anymore, but the 'active' class is still not removed

Comment: Can you post your css, or the the third party css and js libraries' URLs if you are using them

Comment: it's quiet long, so I pasted it here: https://pastebin.com/Zd7DFCca